# Cauchy and residue theorem of the following integral

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

All,

According to the residue theorem, from the following integral, we can get

$$
\begin{split}
\int_c t^k \cdot \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t} &=4\pi i \zeta^k
\end{split}
$$
where $k \geq 1$ and $c$ is a unit circle. Also, $\zeta^k = e^{k \theta i} = \cos k \theta + i \sin k \theta$

My question is, what would be the result when $k=0?$

I have derived the integral below but still not sure if this is correct.

$$
\begin{split}
\int_c t^k \cdot \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t} = \int_c \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t}
\end{split}
$$

by using partial fraction expansion of the integrand, of the form as follow:

$$\frac{t+\zeta}{(t-\zeta)t} = \frac{A}{t-\zeta}+\frac{B}{t}$$

Multiplying thorough and compare the terms in the numerator, we get,

$$t+\zeta=At+B(t-\zeta)=(A+B)t-B\zeta$$

which can be solved for $A=2$ and $B=-1$, hence

$$\frac{t+\zeta}{(t-\zeta)t}=\frac{2}{t-\zeta}+\frac{1}{t}$$

using this last form, we can break the initial integrand becomes,

$$
\begin{split}
\int_c \frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta} \frac{dt}{t}
\end{split} = \int_c \frac{2}{t-\zeta}dt-\int_c \frac{dt}{t} = 2\pi i(2)-2\pi i = 2\pi i
$$

is this correct?

Comment: What is the exact meaning of $c$ ??

Comment: $c$ is a unit circle.

Comment: I don't think your first formula is correct. Since you are taking $\zeta$ on the circle the integral does not exist.

Comment: The first is correct for the following reason: the residue is $2\zeta^k$. Thus the final result: $2\pi i(residue) = 2\pi i(2\zeta) = 4\pi i \zeta^k$